# Copy and pasting multiple items to the clipboard in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, is it possible to have multiple items in your clipboard and choose which item to paste? What are the keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 42):

Yes, it is possible.

Whilst <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is normally used to paste, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (IntelliJ Default Key map) which will bring a pop-up of the items in the clipboard to paste.

The default size of the clipboard is 5; it will show the last five things have have been copied. The option to change this is called "Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard". You can change it quickly by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and typing the name of the setting.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + V is a gem!\

Comment: Unfortunately, that configuration option has disappeared from IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2, at least on Windows. (Exactly which version removed it, I don't know.) Nonetheless, [it remains documented](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.2/working-with-source-code.html#copy_paste). Despite its disappearance from the GUI, the setting remains in effect on one of my machines (to which I do not have access currently). Anyone know where in the various configuration files this setting is stored?

Comment: Just to add that on Mac the shortcut is `Cmd+Shift+V`

Comment: It changed my life! 

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and on Mac use  <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to see your clipboard history.

**Change Stored History Size**

Click <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>, type `Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard`, and then edit the value in the dialog.

[image]

To manually find the setting, open: `Preferences -> Editor -> General` and then in the `Limits` section of the main `General` page, increase `Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard`. I changed mine to 50.

[image]

## Alternatively, copy and paste multiple lines at once

You can select adjacent line content, random line/positions etc. with multi-caret selection.

[Read how to here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266889/974045)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> will bring up the popup like:

Press <kbd>shift</kbd> will help you to choose multiple paste items, then cllick OK.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

to increase clipboard history max item:
shift + shift 
search for 'registry'
click on 'Registry...'
search for 'clipboard.history.max.items'
increase it's value