# Can you increase the paste buffer size in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

The ctrl-shift-v paste buffer in IntelliJ is great, but only holds 5 items. Is it possible to increase the size of this buffer?

Similar to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716793/copy-and-pasting-multiple-items-to-the-clipboard-in-intelli-j-idea#comment29733286_1716797) on another question

Searching within IntelliJ settings hasn't shown up anything, neither has google.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in IntelliJ 15?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

## Yes

Go to:

```
File > Settings > Editor > Limits > Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard
```

...and change the number.

**Update for IntelliJ 14 and Android Studio 1.2**
In new versions, it appears under a slightly different level in the menu...

Go to:
File > Settings > Editor > **General**
Then scroll down to find:
Limits > Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard

If they decide to move it again, you can always just search for "max clipboard", that is:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Then type "max clipboard" in the dialog that comes up.

[image]

Comment: Now it's Editor -> General -> Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard

Comment: I am using IntelliJ 2019.3 and I cannot see that option anywhere, search is not finding it. The clipboard history size is definitely bigger than 20 by default. Did they remove the limit completely?

Comment: they removed it 2019.3.3

Comment: Setting moved to IJ Registry (`clipboard.history.max.items`) : see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61538315/1677594

Answer (score 20):

For **IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1** it can be done by edit properties in Registry.
Goes to **Help > Find Action**  and type Registry

[image: registry]

[image: search for clipboard]

Answer (score 8):

Goes to 
**File > Settings > Editor > General**
And then find **Limits** section

[image]

Comment: looks like this option was removed from here and added new `recent locations limit`(not same)