# IntelliJ: add the same text at the beginning of multiple lines?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I easily add the same text at the beginning of multiple lines of code in IntelliJ?

In Vim, I'd normally do this with a visual block (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) then selecting the lines, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> before typing the text to be inserted and finally Esc.

Is there something equivalent in IntelliJ?

Comment: It's possible to use "Multicursor" feature in IDEA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262737/intellij-idea-way-of-editing-multiple-lines

Comment: Super cool. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ IDEA way of editing multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262737/intellij-idea-way-of-editing-multiple-lines)